# Can we use useReducer hook to create product detail page

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-hooks, react-redux, react-router

I am trying to create product detail page, i want to know if we can create it with just useReducer hook or we need Redux for this.....

This is my product page

```js
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import "./RecentlyAdd.css";
import useCard from "../../../Hooks/useStoreCard";
import { Container, Column } from "..//..//../Styled-Components/RecentlyAdd";

export default function RecentlyAdd({ lightBg, imgStart }) {
  const { docs } = useCard("Images");

  const Products = docs.map((doc) => {
    return (
      <div className="col-sm-3 m-5">
        <div key={doc.id} className="card shadow p-2 mb-3 bg-white rounded">
          <img className="card-img-top" src={doc.url} alt="Card image cap" />
          <div className="card-body">
            <h5 className="card-title">{doc.Title}</h5>
            <p className="card-text">{doc.Place}</p>
            <p className="card-text">{doc.Year}</p>
            <a className="btn btn-primary">
                <Link to={`/products/${doc.id}`}>{doc.Title}
                </Link>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  });

  return (
    <div
      className={lightBg ? "home__hero-section" : "home__hero-section darkBg"}
    >
      <Container>
        <div
          className="row"
          style={{
            display: "flex",
            flexDirection: imgStart === "start" ? "row-reverse" : "row",
          }}
        >
          <Column>{Products}</Column>
        </div>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I want to open a new page with all detail when someone clicks on link page opens with product id but i don't know how to add detail i am using firebase do i need redux or i can do it other way like using useReducer hook or something.....

Comment: When you change page to the detail page, do you fetch data for the detail page? Or will you pass the data from the docs object to the detail page? Can you post the code where you are fetching the products data? In useCard? You are saying that you use firebase. Firebase have hooks you can use to get data from your store https://github.com/CSFrequency/react-firebase-hooks/blob/master/firestore/README.md#usecollection. You tried this?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how you could implement using the context api. Where we use the context to fetch the products and store them in the context state. Then we use that state in both the ProductsPage to show all products and on the ProductDetailsPage to show a specific product.

```
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Link,
  useParams,
  Route,
  Routes
} from "react-router-dom";
import { createContext, useContext } from "react";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <ProductsProvider>
        <div className="App">
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<ProductsPage />} />
            <Route path="/product/:id" element={<ProductDetailsPage />}></Route>
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </ProductsProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

const ProductsContext = createContext({});

const ProductsProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const docs = [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: "test",
      place: "Place1",
      year: "Year1",
      url: "url1"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: "test2",
      place: "Place2",
      year: "Year2",
      url: "url2"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: "test3",
      place: "Place3",
      year: "Year3",
      url: "url3"
    }
  ];

  const getProductDetails = (productId) => {
    return docs.find((x) => x.id === productId);
  };

  return (
    <ProductsContext.Provider
      value={{
        docs,
        getProductDetails
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </ProductsContext.Provider>
  );
};

const ProductsPage = () => {
  const { docs } = useContext(ProductsContext);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Products</h1>
      {docs &&
        docs.map((doc) => {
          return (
            <div className="col-sm-3 m-5">
              <div
                key={doc.id}
                className="card shadow p-2 mb-3 bg-white rounded"
              >
                <img
                  className="card-img-top"
                  src={doc.url}
                  alt="Card image cap"
                />
                <div className="card-body">
                  <h5 className="card-title">{doc.title}</h5>
                  <p className="card-text">{doc.place}</p>
                  <p className="card-text">{doc.year}</p>
                  <a className="btn btn-primary">
                    <Link to={`/product/${doc.id}`}>{doc.title}</Link>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
    </div>
  );
};

const ProductDetailsPage = () => {
  const params = useParams();
  const productId = parseInt(params["id"]);
  const { getProductDetails } = useContext(ProductsContext);
  const product = getProductDetails(productId);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Product details for {productId}</h1>
      <h3>{product.title}</h3>
      <h3>{product.year}</h3>
      <Link to="/">Back to products list</Link>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Here is the codesandbox link if you want to see it in action: https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-meninsky-yfpizw

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of solutions to the problem you are describing. Now I want to elaborate on two of them:

1. I assume you are using [React Router](https://reactrouter.com/) as Routing Library? If not you should probably consider to do so! The easiest solution would be navigating to a route where you set the id of the specific product as param. Then you just get the param from the url by using the function [useParams](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams) on the detail page and fetch the products detail information from firebase. This avoids adding a heavy library like redux to your project.
2. You could also use the hook useContext which is already part of ReactJs. An easy example on how to do it can be found [here](https://dev.to/ms_yogii/usecontext-for-better-state-management-51hi).

Have fun with the solutions!

Comment: I  have used useContext before but in this case i don't know how to if i creat a context and get all data of documents then pass it to app then how can i match document id with product id its little complicated

Comment: Why don't you use the documentIds as productIds?

Comment: I don't understand that